# How to disable floating label animation when populating EditText Fields wrapped in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout, androiddesignsupport

I would like to be able to have the floating label already in place when I pre-populate the EditText field. When the view loads, the hint is still displayed behind the text before it is animated to the floating label. There doesn't seem to be a method for this in Support Library's TextInputLayout.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the support design library **v23** you can use:

```
til.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
```

Here you can find the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintAnimationEnabled(boolean)).

Comment: One note, the animation need to be turned off before we set the text/hint. Having the sequence wrong would not turn off the animation.

Comment: Working. Make sure that you call the method on your `TextInputEditText` and not `TextINputLayout`.
The animation is played, after you set the fields, and then enable the animation again though. :-((

Comment: @Sevastyan You don't really need the animation until the field is cleared. Add a text change listener and re-enable animations when the field's character count reaches 0.

Answer (score 3):

Based Gabriels answer I wrote a small method to run after loading the view hierarchy that disables animation on initial display but enables it after wards. Add this to your Base Activity/Fragment/View and it will solve it issue.

```
private void setTextInputLayoutAnimation(View view) {
        if (view instanceof TextInputLayout) {
            TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) view;
            til.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
            til.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    til.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    til.setHintAnimationEnabled(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return;
        }

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
            for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = group.getChildAt(i);
                setTextInputLayoutAnimation(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution using below code, i tried using xml but not working longer, you can try as to set hint programatically to both *TextInputLayout* and *TextInputEditText*

```
    TextInputLayout hintView = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_login_inputlayout_password);
    hintView.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
    hintView.setHint("");
    yourEditTextPassword.setHint(getString(R.string.text_password_hint));
```